# Cloudkit: "ZoneId provided doesn't match target zone"

Tags: ios, swift, cloud, icloud, cloudkit

I have this piece of code:

```
func saveProfileForCheck(check: Check) {
    let toSave = CKRecord(recordType: "Check", zoneID: sharedStore.checksID!)
    let profile = check.profile as Profile!
    toSave.setValue(NSString(format: "%i", check.closed), forKey: "closed")
    toSave.setValue(check.date, forKey: "date")
    toSave.setValue(NSString(format: "%i", check.paid), forKey: "paid")
    toSave.setValue(CKReference(recordID: profile.dbRecordID, action: CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf), forKey: "profile")

    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [toSave], recordIDsToDelete: [check.id])
    operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.delegate?.cloudKitReturnedError(error!)
        } else {
            self.modifiedCheck(check, newRecord: savedRecords![0] as CKRecord )

        }
    }
    privateDB.addOperation(operation)
}
```

It's supposed to save a `profile` property on a `Check` object in my `Checks` RecordZone. When I trigger this function, I get this error:

```
 <CKError 0x7f8c2046d630: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; uuid = EF4CCE3F-3CDB-4506-BA43-464D7D9BD0F6; container ID = "mycontainer"; partial errors: {
130BD962-295C-4601-9343-2E4F4014C8C7:(Checks:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x7f8c2045c680: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "ZoneId provided doesn't match target zone">
... 1 "Batch Request Failed" CKError's omited ...
```

}>

I have attempted several things:

- Checked whether the zoneID is actually correct, which it is.
- Hard-coded the zoneID as a CKRecordZoneID object in the method.
- Looked up the error on google and SO, which does not have result.

Please be aware that `sharedstore.checksID` is an actual ID instead of a string, which is created on app launch when all record zones are fetched.

How would I be able to solve this error? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to set the zoneID on the operation wit something like:

```
    operation.zoneID = CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: sharedStore.checksID!, ownerName: "your name")
```

Update: As discussed below the `.zoneID` is only available on a `CKQqueryOperation` and not a `CKModifyRecordsOperation`

I believe it's only possible to set a CKReference to a record that is in the same zone. Is that the case? If not, then could you try saving the record without that reference?

From the documentation:

> Treat each custom zone as a single unit of data that is separate from
>   every other zone in the database. Inside the zone, you add records as
>   you would anywhere else. You can also create links between the records
>   inside a zone by using the CKReference class. However, the CKReference
>   class does not support cross-zone linking, so each reference object
>   must point to a record in the same zone as the current record

**update:**
it is possible to add a reference across databases (public and private) provided the source and target of the reference are in the default zone.

Comment: I tried that. Actually did this: CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: "Checks", ownerName: CKRecordZoneDefaultName). I do appreciate the comment though, any other thoughts?

Comment: Updated the question, maybe clarifies it a bit. You must be in the consideration that my sharedstore.checksID is an NSString or something, but it actually is a legitimate CKRecordZoneID object. I know it's legit, because I use it in all my cloud operations, and it works like a charm everywhere, except for this particular function

Comment: ok, but then still you need to set it on the operation, not only on the record. like operation.zoneID = sharedStore.checksID!

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I'll try that as soon as I have access to a pc tomorrow

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work as CKModifyRecordsOperation doesn't have a property like 'zoneID'. I'm afraid there must be something wrong with the zoneID I provide in the record type, but I have no idea what as the exact same thing works perfectly in other methods, even modify methods for other record types. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to have accepted your answer only this late, I have been busy with other tasks the last couple of days.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer Just feel it would help other's if you could mention that it is possible to add reference across databases (public and private) provided the source and target of the reference are in the default zone. That is the only way to link public and private records.